# s3cmd Amazon s3 update metadata only

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have a few GB of files on S3, and I need to mass update the metadata for all of them. I know that s3cmd can update the metadata when you transfer a file:

`s3cmd -m text/html --add-header='Content-Encoding: gzip' put [files] s3://...`

However I don't want to retransfer the files to S3. Can s3cmd update the metadata of a key **only** without transferring the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be possible in the future for s3cmd:
https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/37